# when I removed footer in my homepage, other plugin not work on wordpress foundation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I wanna add my own footer,other plugin not work such as slideshow (name: Ultimate Responsive Image Slider) and plugin (name:video-player)... so please help me!!!!!

Here is code:

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="twevle columns"><h1>Test Footer</h1></div>
</div>
<?php //get_footer(); ?>
```

[click it for show images footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW5sJ.png) |
[click here for show images Slideshow not work:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw1vf.jpg)

Comment: This will need much more information, specifically what plugins? What do you mean by "not work"? Do you see an error message? What does `get_footer()` consist of?

Comment: After looking up the docs: Try adding `wp_footer();` to your footer file. It might add the relevant functions, if it works I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: in footer file has wp_footer(); already. but I want to removed get_footer() only in my homepage, but when i removed it, it effect to other plugin as i told u.

Comment: Very thank you bro, now it work.

Comment: @srempen did you see my answer about move wp_footer() to end of body ? or how did you solve it ?

Comment: I replace get_footer to wp_footer() so it work. @ J.Tural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the footer have the call for wp_footer()
that load the JS libraries

in main page where you dont want footer add

```
wp_footer();
```

to the bottom of the main page .